# Most efficient way to execute multiple scalar functions per row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to speed up my query. I need to run 2 scalar-valued functions per row with a couple of the columns as parameters.

The functions do a calculation based on running totals, and there is no easy way (that I'm aware of) to do this in SQL server 2008.

The CTE portion of my query gets all the rows I need the calculations for, and it needs to be run individually for each level. The relationship for Clients to Stores is One-to-Many, but you can't get the calculation at the client level (Store='All') based on the each of its stores calculations.

My first attempt was to have the function calls in the 'SELECT' statement, but I read that they would running synchronously which is not necessary. The attempt below was trying to turn the calculation into a table-value in an attempt to run them Asynchronously.

I was wondering if OUTER APPLY is the way to go, or if there were a more efficient way to go about this.

Let me know if more info is needed!

```
DECLARE @StartTime INT
SET @StartTime=20170101

DECLARE @EndTime INT
SET @EndTime=20170131


;WITH IsAvgStores AS (
    SELECT
        COALESCE(ParentClient,'All') AS ParentClient,
        COALESCE(Client,'All') AS Client,
        COALESCE(Store,'All') AS Store,
        MAX(Answer_Threshold),
        MAX(SL_Threshold)
    FROM 
        client_hierarchy
    WHERE 
        GETDATE() BETWEEN EFF_BEGIN_DATE AND EFF_END_DATE 
    GROUP BY ROLLUP(ParentClient,Client,Store)
)
SELECT I.ParentClient,I.Client,I.Store
    ,SL.isAvg_SL_String
    ,A.isAvg_ASA_String
INTO #isAvgTemp
FROM IsAvgStores I
    OUTER APPLY ( SELECT dbo.isAvg_S_B(ParentClient,Client,Store,Answer_Threshold,@StartTime,@EndTime) AS isAvg_SL_String 
                ) SL
    OUTER APPLY ( SELECT dbo.isAvg_A_B(ParentClient,Client,Store,SL_Threshold,@StartTime,@EndTime)     AS isAvg_ASA_String
                ) A
WHERE ParentClient<>'All'

SELECT * 
FROM #isAvgTemp
```

Comment: I am not seeing how the rollup is working

Comment: @Paparazzi you are right, I forgot to add in the MAX() on the thresholds.

Answer (score 5):

The `outer apply` is redundant for a scalar valued function. You can just do:

```
SELECT I.ParentClient, I.Client, I.Store,
      dbo.isAvg_S_B(ParentClient, Client, Store,A nswer_Threshold, @StartTime, @EndTime) AS isAvg_SL_String,
      dbo.isAvg_A_B(ParentClient, Client, Store, SL_Threshold, @StartTime, @EndTime) as isAvg_ASA_String
INTO #isAvgTemp
FROM IsAvgStores I
WHERE ParentClient <> 'All';
```

This will have absolutely no affect on performance; it just simplifies the query.

For performance, you have three options:

- Rewrite the code to remove the functions; use `outer apply` for the running sums.
- Rewrite the code to remove the functions; use recursive CTEs for the running sums.
- Rewrite the code to remove the functions; use cursors for the running sums.

None of these are optimal. The first two might work if the individual groups are small. The third can be the best option in this circumstance -- and note that I pretty much abhor cursors.

Or, you best option: Upgrade to a later version of SQL Server and use the cumulative sum function provided in SQL Server 2012+.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to try converting the scalar functions to [inline table-valued functions](http://sqlmag.com/print/sql-server/inline-scalar-functions) (ITVF) that return a scalar value. This may or may not work in your scenario. In my experience, [complex scalar functions generally perform poorly in SQL Server on larger result sets](https://sqlserverfast.com/?s=user+defined+ugly) because they are run RBAR. With an ITVF, SQL Server is able to inline the query to optimize the query plan.

Your query would look similar to what you were trying to accomplish with the `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT I.ParentClient, I.Client, I.Store, SL.isAvg_SL_String A.isAvg_ASA_String
INTO #isAvgTemp
FROM IsAvgStores I
OUTER APPLY dbo.isAvg_S_B(ParentClient,Client,Store,Answer_Threshold,@StartTime,@EndTime)SL
OUTER APPLY dbo.isAvg_A_B(ParentClient,Client,Store,SL_Threshold,@StartTime,@EndTime) A
WHERE ParentClient <> 'All';
```

The difference being that your functions would return a table with a single result instead:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.isAvg_S_B (...)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
(
    SELECT ... AS 'isAvg_SL_String'
    FROM ...
);
```

Again, this may or may not improve performance in your particular scenario, but I figure it's worth a shot to prevent duplicating code.